# Access the host network from the vmplayer

Tags: networking, vmware-player

I can't access the host network from my vmplayer guest. I've tried different settings and telnet keeps saying "Connect failed". My current configuration is

```
network: bridged
guest IP: 10.0.3.152
default gateway: 10.0.3.1
host: Ubuntu 10.4 (64 bit)
guest: Windows XP
```

Is 10.0.3.1 the IP of my host?

I think so and pinging it works. Pinging other IPs from the range doesn't work. Accessing the Internet works, accessing the host does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you bridged the connection, the gateway is the address of your router, not the host! This is assigned to the guest because of DHCP.

To get the IP of the host, assuming it's Windows, you'll need to execute `ipconfig` on the host itself.

Comment: As I wrote it isn't Windows, but `ifconfig` did it. Indeed it's 10.0.3.150, far beyond the range I've tried. My bad... it's the IP assigned by my router which I should have known!

Comment: Good stuff if that worked. Sorry about the mixup with Windows, I mixed up your host and guest.